# How is this generic function working?

Tags: vb.net, linq, generics

When I see a function call of the form:

```
Dim i as Integer = getAnInteger("I am groot")
```

I can figure out that the signature of `getAnInteger` should be something like

```
Function getAnInteger(inp As String) As Integer
```

Now, I have this call:

```
Property Name As String
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value as String)
        _name = value
        doSomething(Function() Name)  '<---- this one
    End Set
End Property
```

I figured out that `doSomething` must have been defined like

```
Sub doSomething(ByVal fnName As Func(Of String))
                     '
                     ' or
                     '
Sub doSomething(Of T)(ByVal fnName As Func(Of T)) '....................(1)
```

I found out it to be

```
Sub doSomething(Of T)(ByVal fnName As Expression(Of Func(Of T))) '.....(2)
```

### Question

How come both `Func(Of T)` and `Expression(Of Func(Of T))` can accept the argument `Function() Name` where `Name` is a String type property. Also, `Expression` is in `Linq` namespace. So the argument must be a linq expression. But, `Function() Name` is not Linq! it is plain delegate to `Name` property. So how is this thing working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Expression(Of T)` is a special type that compiler knows about, and that's where the magic is.

When you assign a lambda expression (like mentioned `Function() Name`) to a delegate type (e.g. `Func(Of String)`) compiler will generate an executable code, but when you assign the same lambda expression to `Expression(Of Func(Of String))` it will generate an [**Expression Tree**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/09/11/lambda-expressions-and-expression-trees.aspx), which is a tree structure that represents your code.

It's useful mostly for Query Providers, e.g. Entity Framework uses it to generate proper SQL code that can be run against a database.

You can convert `Expression(Of Func(Of String))` to `Func(Of String)` at runtime by calling `Compile` method. Converting `Func(Of String)` to `Expression(Of Func(String))` is, up to my knowledge, not possible. You can create the tree manually using `Expression` class methods, but there is nothing that would make it happen automatically by just passing a delegate to it.

Comment: ... *Expression(Of T) is a special type that compiler knows about, and that's where the magic is* ... thanks.